# Conflict between two jQuery's scripts

Tags: jquery, fancybox, conflict, buddypress

I'm spanish (sorry for my english), and it's the first time that i write here for ask something.

After hours of debugging and searching why the Fancybox script didn't work i search a conflict between two scripts in my website (now in Maintence Mode)

I use a few scripts on my website, but I can safely say that I have a conflict between these two scripts:

```
http://www.planetdescargas.com/wp-content/themes/bigfoot/javascripts/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js    
http://www.planetdescargas.com/wp-content/themes/bigfoot/javascripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js
```

AND

```
http://www.planetdescargas.com/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/global.js?ver=3.0.5
```

The first two scripts is the plugin for jquery "[fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)", the other is the main javascript (Ajax) for wordpress plugin: BuddyPress.

The latter creates conflict in fancybox. If I remove BuddyPress' script, fancybox works perfectly, but if not, fancybox don't work.

BuddyPress' script, global.js has a variable defined at the outset that is the one that makes the script.
I try to define it this way:

var jq = jQuery.noConflict ();

But still not working.

Any suggestions?

In Firebug console i got this:

```
c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || a] is not a function
```

[Detener en este error] e,this.options.orig[e]);this.options.c...++)ab||a.splice(b--,1);a.length||

Line 143 of

```
http://www.planetdescargas.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, when the global.js script is in the page, Fancybox it's not working

Comment: Juan: Please use Chrome or FireFox, then open Developer Tools or FireBug respectively and check the console for errors. I assume there will be errors since your scripts aren't doing anything, so edit your question with the error message(s).

Comment: In Firebug console i got this:

    c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || a] is not a function
[Detener en este error] e,this.options.orig[e]);this.options.c...++)a[b]()||a.splice(b--,1);a.length|| 

Line 143 of

    http://www.planetdescargas.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2

Comment: Please try removing the `noConflict()` function. I can easily picture that killing other scripts.

Comment: I got the same error with or without the noConflict()

Comment: c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || a] is not a function
http://www.planetdescargas.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2
Line 143

Comment: Well I can only argue that you shouldn't be using bad javascript scripts that kill the jQuery globals

Comment: Okey i don't know what was the problem, but i solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use this way.

Open the `wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/_inc/global.js`

Add on top:

```
jQuery.noConflict (jquery_working =! html bind);
```

Go to line **#1264**
Add this below:

```
;(function(jQuery){  ///Add this before start jQuery.easing.
  jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {def:"easeOutQuad",swing:function(e,f,a,h,g){return ......
  // ...
})(jQuery); //Add this end of the call.
```

Similarly you can resolve the jQuery Cookie plugin conflict error.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you use `jQuery.noConflict()`. `noConflict()` releases control of the `$` symbol. From what I see from your other scripts though, they use the safe way (`(function($){ }(jQuery))`) so using `noConflicts()` has no actual effect.

Change this

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict ();
```

into this:

```
jQuery.noConflict ();
var jq = jQuery;
```

To make sure.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Still not working.
I'm using Wordpress' jQuery.

Global.js is loaded as a dependency, fancybox no, I do not know if that is relevant

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong, but i solved the problem. I use this code in my functions.php in my theme root:

```
    function fancybox_js() {
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery.fancybox', 'http://www.planetdescargas.com/wp-content/themes/bigfoot/javascripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.3.4');
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery.easing', 'http://www.planetdescargas.com/wp-content/themes/bigfoot/javascripts/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js', array('jquery'), '1.3');
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery.mousewheel', 'http://www.planetdescargas.com/wp-content/themes/bigfoot/javascripts/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js', array('jquery'), '3.0.4');
    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fancybox_js', 999);
```

I took the libraries from a wordpress plugin called [Easy Fancybox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-fancybox/installation/), and now all work fine. Thanks!