# c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || a] is not a function when using JQuery Easing plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Trying to use JQuery Easing plugin in my wordpress but its giving me following error (firebug)

```
c.easing[this.options.specialEasing && this.options.specialEasing[this.prop] || a] is not a function
```

I have included JQuery 1.4.2 and after doing some googling have included addeded even `jquery.easing.compatibility.js` along with `jquery.easing.1.3.js` but still the problem is there.

Can any one let me know what might be the issue.As an additional note i am also using fancybox so have following js included in my code

```
jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js
jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js
```

Hers is the code i am using

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function anim(duration){
        $('#mint').animate(
            {height: 'toggle'},
            {duration: duration, specialEasing: {height: 'easeOutBounce'}}
        );
    }

    $('#closebtn').click(function() {
        $('#mintbar').slideUp();
        anim(800);
    });

    $('#mint').click(function() {
        anim(500);
        $('#mintbar').slideDown('slow','easeOutBounce');
    });
});
```

Comment: what type of easing are you using? I mean like "swing" etc..

Comment: @elclanrs: i have updated my post with the js code

Comment: Have you tried with other types just in case that's the problem? And also check you're calling easing plugin without any typos.

Comment: Also, look at this similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783695/conflict-between-two-jquerys-scripts

Comment: @elclanrs: when i tested this code in standalone web-page its working fine only issue i am facing when i am adding it to my wordpress :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say it works standalone but not with WordPress then it's probably because you're in `noConflict` mode so you need to use `jQuery` instead of its shortcut, `$`. Instead of `$('#mint')`, do `jQuery('#mint')`. Same for every other jQuery object.

How are you including jQuery in WordPress anyway? It already comes bundled with it. If you're attaching your own version, you need to do it the proper way. Every other script should be loaded in `functions.php` too, and not in the header.

In **functions.php**

```
function my_add_scripts() {

    // Unload bundled jQuery
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    // jQuery
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', ('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'), 0, 0, 1 );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    // mousewheel
    wp_register_script( 'mousewheel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mousewheel.js', 0, 0, 1 );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mousewheel' );

    // fancybox
    wp_register_script( 'fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fancybox.js', 0, 0, 1 );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_add_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs regarding `$`,its working for me for other functions like fancy-box and few other places and yes have included JQuery in the header section, will try to do as per your suggestion

Comment: using above code means i have to change `$` with `JQuery` throughout my website which means whole lot of rework

Comment: Thanks for the heads up i used `JQeury` in place of `$` for the code block i mentioned in my post and it worked like charm